# Scribite overwrite path for CKEditor template

Tags: symfony, ckeditor, zikula

I want to have for admin the full toolbar but for the users the zikula configured one.
I figured out already which template to change:

```
modules/zikula/ScribiteModule/Editor/CKEditor/Resources/views/editorheader.html.twig
```

Of course I can just change it there. But I want to be safe in case of Scribite update. So I know I have to place my changed copy into

```
app/resources/ZikulaScribiteModule/...
```

What is the ...?

Same question for the toolbar configuration file

```
modules/zikula/ScribiteModule/Editor/CKEditor/vendor/ckeditor/custconfig.js
```

Where is this file going?

I asked that question already some months ago: [How can I manage to have two different toolbars in CKEditor for two different groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42225553/how-can-i-manage-to-have-two-different-toolbars-in-ckeditor-for-two-different-gr)
But now the ScribiteModule is transfered to the new symfony stile and not Zikula legacy anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure you cannot override these templates as they are in non-standard locations from a traditional Symfony model (intentionally).

You may be able to assign a different editor using a textarea override, if the textareas have different DOM ids

Comment: Is there a chance to change Scribite that way so I would be able to override my template? If there is a chance I would create a feature request.

For the Moment I did my changes inside the module itself and have to rmember to redo it after upgrade.